# How many robots is too many robots?

Tags: chickens

After playing [Chickens!](https://gamehelp16.github.io/chickens/) for a while and buying a few upgrades, I can now purchase robots.  However, they offer the following warning:

> Robots help you to slay chickens automatically in this world and NOT chickenverse, they slay normal chickens, iron chickens and gold chickens only since the other type of chickens will attack you
>
> WARNING: Don't buy too many of them! This world has limited number of chickens, they breed, but if you make too many of robots there will be no more chickens and the robots won't do anything

So how many robots can I build without depleting the population?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a clear answer, as it depends on circumstances.

The game keeps a population of each kind of chicken, and every interval it breeds some, and every interval (a different one) robots kill some. A bit into the game you can learn the skill Statistics that will allow you to see the population of each kind of chicken.

Here come the numbers:

Every breed interval (2 seconds default, 1.75 sec with medicine), the chickens breed. Every kind's population grows by current_kind_population/1000, up to the maximum of 999999999999.

Robots run every 3 seconds and each one of them kills between 2 and 10 normal chickens, between 1 and 6 iron chickens and between 0 and 2 gold chickens (all ranges are inclusive).

Therefore, to make sure your (for example normal chicken) population isn't hunted out, the following must hold:

```
normal_chicken_pop/1000 * 3 >= number_of_robots * 10 * 2
```

Where the 10 on the right side is the maximum of normal chickens the robots can hunt, and the 2 and 3 are to make both respective time intervals the same length (with no medicine). Similar process applies to other kinds of chickens.

Source: The game code

Comment: Also, if your chickens don't seem to breed or robots aren't harvesting, try "turning it off and on again" (saving the game, closing the panel, and then going to the game's address again)

Answer (score -2):

Just leave your game on the charger and leave it on at night and it will breed so many chickens!!!

[image: My chickens!!]

Comment: The user asked *"How many robots is too many robots?"* and *"So how many robots can I build without depleting the population?"*. Your answer does not seem to approach the question, but instead gives advice that is not directly related.

Please make sure that your answers actually engage with what is being asked.

What you have said might work well as a bit of information to go along with a propper answer, but unfortunately does not work by its self.